# Is it possible to run logistic regression on data with a few longitudinal parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, r, logistic-regression

Currently, I am building a credit rating model based on logistic regression and faced a problem with inserting panel variables in it. Is it possible to do so in logistic regression and if it is, what packages and functions can deal with it?